# extending the Windows property handler for jpeg files

Tags: c++, windows, atl, windows-shell

I have jpeg files that contain embedded XMP data (in addition to EXIF fields).  The users want to be able to view the XMP data in the Windows Explorer property dialog (Details tab).  I am considering "extending" the default property handler (C:\Windows\System32\PhotoMetadataHandler.dll) to let it handle the system properties and then add the additional XMP properties from my code.

I have found good samples for writing property handlers, but they all work under the assumption that you are creating new type of file.  Can anyone offer any experience in dealing with the "system" property handlers?  They seem to do things a bit differently than the approaches described by MS for developing new property handlers.

Comment: If you want user to see properties only in Property dialog why don`t you want to use simple property sheet shell extension instead of property handler?

Comment: Good suggestion Denis, wasn't aware of those.  The other requirement is for the users to be able  to find files by searching the jpeg XMP data, but I think I can implement a custom IFilter for that.